# Ligatures not formed when using MinionPro with Inconsolata

Tags: font-encodings, ligatures, minionpro

I use Minion in a document via the MinionPro package, and now I want to use Inconsolata for, amongst other things, code listings.  When I include the fontenc package with the T1 option for Inconsolata, ligatures for “fi”, “fl”, etc. appear as separate characters in Minion.  If I don’t use fontenc, I can see the ligatures, but some characters like “>” are not displayed in my code listings in Inconsolata.

Any idea what I could try?  I use pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 from TeX Live on an Ubuntu system.

A small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\begin{document}

Please save the following to a file:

\begin{verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        printf("No parameters.\n");
    else
        printf("Hello.\n");
}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the fontenc package line, the `>` disappears in the output, but I get the “fi” ligature in “file”; as is, I get the `>`, but separate characters for “fi”.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @lev Hope the example is enough.

Comment: As far as I can see, it seems that switching to LY1 encoding works well.

Comment: The fi ligature shows up correctly for me when I compile your MWE.

Comment: Your MWE works for me, so it must be something with your installation. When you compile your MWE do you get any errors like `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file base-MinionPro-ab.enc): cannot open
encoding file for reading`?